# Django Passing objects from template to view

Tags: javascript, python, django, object, django-models

I really like the django template language, but when it comes to passing more than a string from templates to views I have no clue. Therefore I want to figure out which modern tool to use.

What would you suggest to learn next to tackle such tasks or is there a way in django which I haven't discovered yet?

**Edit:** I know about querying objects. What I'am looking for is to pass the object back with all it's attributes.

A simple model of foo:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am passing an instances via `foos = foo.objects.all()` to a template. On the template they getting processed like this:

Here, as textfield with autocomplete:

```
<form method="POST" action="/path/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="btn btn-default" name="foo" list="foos">
    <datalist id="foos">
    {% for foo in foos %}
        <option value="{{ foo }}">
    {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
    <button class="btn btn-default">send</button>
 </form>
```

And as tiles for every foo instance:

```
<form method="POST" action="/path">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="wrapper">
    {% for category_ in categories %}   
        {% for foo in foos %}
            {% if category_ in foo.categories.all %}
            <input name="foo" type="submit" value="{{ foo }}" class="box box_text">
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
</form>
```

In the `request.POST` I will have the foo name as string. I want to send the whole instance back to a view to process it. It would also work out with just sending `foo.id`. But I don't know how to put `foo.id` into the template without being shown beside `foo.name`, but send as variable in `request.POST`.

In addition to that problem I would like to have an advice what technique to learn for such tasks (JSON, Ajax, ...)

Comment: Are you really asking to pass things from the template to the view? Or the other way round?

Comment: My problem right now is, that I can't figure out how to send more information from the template then the template `{{ variables }}`, which being send as a string. Of course I could send a whole bunch of variables to use them to filter the searched object, but in my case I have tiles with the name of the objects and those can be dublicates (I actually don't now how I could hide the pk and send it as post as well...)

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about exactly what you want to pass and why you think you can't do that in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what the `foo` object actually looks like, I'm going to assume that the following is happening:

1. You're only specifying `foo` within the template.
2. Since that's all you're specifying, Django will attempt to print the object as a string, calling either the object's `__str__` magic method or `__unicode__`.

If you want to ONLY print the name, and then ONLY print the id, just specifically print ONLY those attributes, instead of just `foo`, as in:

```
<option value="{{ foo.id }}">{{ foo.name }}</option>
```

Comment: Yes I also did this, but then foo.id will be shown in the autocomplete field. I want to avoid exactly this. Just the name should be shown, but when it comes to post (by clicking on the tile) more information then a rare string should be send. This is the problem I'am trying to solve

Comment: Why would foo.id be in the autocomplete field? I'm assuming you're using some type of jQuery plugin to provide the autocomplete? What library/plugin?

Comment: No I  created a autocomplete field with `<datalist>` and in there I looped all "foos" `{% for foo in foos %}` to `<option value="{{ foo }}">`. It came to my mind to do it like this after I discovered `datalist` on W3Schools. I don't know if there will be any problems when the foo database will have a lot of instances